# How to check data sent to Omniture/adobe-analytics is correct or not

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am a beginner to Omniture/adobe web analytics. I want to know the some information like

1. How can we track data coming into Omniture?
2. How do we know if the tags are firing as expected?

I installed Omnibug extension and can track what are the parameters and their values being sent to Omniture, but not sure how can we track data in Omniture that was being sent. 
Also, I tried to find unique visitors, visits, pageviews based on pageName. Is it possible to filter unique visitors based on pageName? If yes, can anyone guide me by providing list of instructions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do to truly verify that the expected data is landing in Adobe Analytics is look at the Click Stream feeds and map the results against the data you expect to be there. https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/clickstream/

It is not trivial, but is the deepest way of verifying the final result of page code, data collection, processing rules, vista and finally pre/post results.